# Why do these alerts multiply?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK, i have a couple of inputs. I have this code to validate them.

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $("#first_name").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            isFormValid = false;
        }
    });

    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please Enter Your First Name");
    return isFormValid;
});

$("#form1").submit(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $("#last_name").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            isFormValid = false;
        }
    });

    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please Enter Your Last Name");
    return isFormValid;
});    

    $("#form1").submit(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $("#dropdown").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            isFormValid = false;
        }
    });

    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please Select Your Volunteer Choice");
    return isFormValid;
});
```

For some reason, i get a message after a message. What i was aiming for is that it only show me the next field that has not been field out, not all of them at the same time. If you have a question, please comment, it is hard to explain....do not down vote until you give me a chance to better explain.
​

Comment: Java != Javascript...

Comment: Well, all three functions are attached to the `submit` handler, so all three functions will be executed every time you submit the form...

Comment: i am sorry, i am young, and really do not know the difference...

Comment: @EliteGamer it's like German and Dutch. ;)

Comment: Let me just say this. Is there an easier, nicer, less complex way of doing this? I am really confused.

Comment: Can someone help me find a solution...like a better way of validating a form...and easier...please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to simplify your code, and make it work like intended.

First, since you use the same method to validate all the fields, wrap that in a function instead of repeating the code:

```
function isFieldEmpty(jQuerySelector) {
    return $.trim($(jQuerySelector).val()).length == 0
}
```

Second, use a single `submit` handler to check everything, and `return false` if any field does not pass validation:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){

    if(isFieldEmpty('#first_name')) {
        alert("Please Enter Your First Name");
        return false;
    }

    if(isFieldEmpty('#last_name')) {
        alert("Please Enter Your Last Name");
        return false;
    }

    if(isFieldEmpty('#dropdown')) {
        alert("Please Select Your Volunteer Choice");
        return false;
    }

    // Will return true only if all fields passed
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Is there any way you can show me on a jsfiddle....I am having trouble implementing it in my code....

Comment: Here it goes. Also, my second alert was wrong (said First instead of Last), fixing it now. http://jsfiddle.net/2mAu7/2/

Comment: Hey! is there a way you could put an email verification together for me...please...i can not find one that is not complex...I would greatly appreciate it...the id="email" Oh! and thank you for the awesome answer! :)

Comment: Here is an answer on how to validate an email with JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/825789

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with JQuery but I think what is happening is your are binding 3 functions to your form, which means they all get called

when you want to do is create 1 function validate that calls your sub validations functions.

also I would recommend you change your sub validation methods to return the message instead of a boolean, this way you can display all the errors in 1 alert.

Comment: Ok, is there any way you can show me this in a jsfiddle or something...i would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple alerts because you bind different functions to the submit event of the form: each one checks a different field and fires an alert if the field is empty.

You need to move the three validation steps in only one function and bind that function to the submit event.

Something like:

```
$("#form1").submit(check);


function check() {
    var isFormValid = true;
    var errors = array();

    $("#first_name").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            isFormValid = false;
            errors.push("Please Enter Your First Name");
        }
    });

    $("#last_name").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            isFormValid = false;
            errors.push("Please Enter Your Last Name");
        }
    });

    $("#dropdown").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            isFormValid = false;
            errors.push("Please Select Your Volunteer Choice");
        }
    });

    if (!isFormValid) {
        var errorMsg = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            errorMsg += errors[i] +  "\n";  
        }
        alert(errorMsg);    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the redundancy on your code, same *function*, same *identifier*, same *logic*, same event *handler*, ***useless each*** with an **id selector**.

The only thing different are the subjects. Here is my suggestion.

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){
    var errors = [];
    if($("#first_name").val().length == 0){
       errors.push("Please Enter Your First Name");
    }

    if($("#last_name").val().length == 0){
       errors.push("Please Enter Your Last Name");
    }
    // and so on

    if(var isFormValid = errors.length > 0) { 
         alert('you have errors'); 
         //errors contains all the error message if you need them
    }
    return isFormValid;
});
```